# GitLab Merge Request attach a file

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge, merge-request

When I try to attach a file on my GitLab Merge Request, I see the below on the description text area,
[image]

My question is does GitLab store the attachments in a temporary storage? Also I see some random ids/keys generated in the path as seen in attachment, where does that come from?

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab stores the files on a server connected databases. It uses CarrierWave for related operations. I believe it would be permanently kept unless it is removed by the GitLab's admin. Based on its official [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/file_storage.html), it doesn't talk about the retention period of the file anywhere.

Speaking of your second question, `/uploads/f866b9da460fde0a9378cac37f6c4548/test.PNG` the second string from left is just a random hash string *(internally system generated)*. You can assume it as the number of attachments can grow exponentially, therefore, Gitlab can use the sharding-mechanism based this random string to upload and fetch your files with ease. You can refer to this [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_types.html) for further details.